# Plotting data vertically with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with a single column of data.  By default, gnuplot renders this on the x-axis from left to right.  However, I want to plot this data vertically from top to bottom.  How can I do this?

The relevant excerpt from my plot file:

```
set size 1.0, 1.0
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color dashed lw 1 "Helvetica" 14                                                      
set output "ocean-diffuse.eps"

set autoscale
set xtic auto
set ytic auto
plot '0000086400.dat' using 1 with line, \
     '0000172800.dat' using 1 with line
```

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far (the code)?

Comment: I've added the plot file but I've not yet found anything in the gnuplot documentation that might help me.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: the `plot` command assumes your file has x-values in the first column, and y-values in the second. so one option would be to swap the data in your files.

Comment: But I only have one column of data (which gnuplot is plotting as y values)

Comment: i would then recommend adding a second column

Comment: Do you mean `plot '0000086400.dat' using 1:0`? That uses your single column as x-values and the row number as y-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the single column used as x-value, use:

```
plot '0000086400.dat' using 1:0
```

That uses the row number (column 0) as y-values. Of course you can do any scaling and computation with the row number as

```
f(x) = x
plot '0000086400.dat' using 1:(f($0))
```

To have the y-axis reversed, use

```
set yrange [*:*] reverse
```

Comment: This does the job nicely!  Slightly more succinctly, `set yrange [] reverse` also works for me.